# Using jQuery .on() to make a drop-down menu

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to make a jQuery drop down menu, that adds a class to know if it's down or up. But for some reason the .on() function doesn't seem to respond to clicks. What are I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML:

```
<ul id="main-menu" class="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="http://example.com">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="drop-down">
        <a href="http://example.com">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>
               <a href="http://example.com">Sub Item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="http://example.com">Sub Item 2</a>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="http://example.com">Sub Item 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="http://example.com">Item 3</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And my JS:

```
// Slide down
jQuery('#main-menu > li.drop-down > a').not('.active a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).closest('li.drop-down').addClass('active').find('ul.sub-menu').slideDown();
});

// Slide up
jQuery('#main-menu > li.drop-down.active > a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).closest('li.drop-down').find('ul.sub-menu').slideUp(400, function(){
        jQuery(this).closest('li.drop-down.active').removeClass('active');
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: would need your html, your selectors are probably wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need 2 handlers for what you are trying to achieve.

You can just use one handler making use of `toggleClass` and `slideToggle` jQuery methods.

```
// Slide down
jQuery('#main-menu').on('click', 'li.drop-down > a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this)
    .closest('li.drop-down')
    .toggleClass('active')
    .find('ul.sub-menu')
    .slideToggle(400, function(){
         if($(this).is(':hidden')){
              jQuery(this).closest('li.drop-down.active').removeClass('active');
         }
    });
});
```

References: **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/), [.slideToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)**

Comment: This is what i did first, but I actually need the active class to stay on when the menu is open (the clicked link background stays white) and then to remove the active class after the menu has slide up. So it needs to be separate up and down code.

Comment: @DrewBaker - Added the code the check if the submenu is hidden then only remove the active class. Take a look at my edited answer.

Comment: You have a semi-colon after closest(), also change the toggleClass() to addClass() and then it works as I need! But I'm still confused as to why .on() didn't work.

Comment: `on` didn't worked because you are attaching `on` on `#main-menu > li.drop-down.active > a` which will give you empty set because `li` will not have `active` class initally when this code will be executed. If you want to take advantage of `on` then take a look at its second parameter where you can specify the selector to trigger events for.

Comment: I thought that was what on() was for, to attach dynamically. That's what live() used to do, which on() has replaced.

Comment: `on` is introduced in jQuery 1.7 and thats when `live` is depricated because `on` can perform `live`'s job too only if second argument is used as selector. I hope this makes sense to you.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) plugin?

Comment: I'd rather not use plugins if I don't have to.